# Adding buttons created in js to the table in html

Tags: javascript, html

hello i have created buttons dynamically using js.now i need these buttons to be presented inside a table format with   in the html table tag help pls

```js
function funchr()
{   
 $( ".hr" ).remove();
 
 var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");      
    var t = document.createTextNode("VIEW PROFILE");      
    btn.appendChild(t);                                
    btn.setAttribute("id","viewid");
    btn.setAttribute("class","vp");
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        
    var t = document.createTextNode("EMPLOYEE DIRECTORY");       
    btn.appendChild(t);                               
    btn.setAttribute("id","empdir");
    btn.setAttribute("class","ed");
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        
    var t = document.createTextNode("CREATE ABSENCE");       
    btn.appendChild(t);                                
    btn.setAttribute("id","crabs");
    btn.setAttribute("class","ca");
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
  }
```

```html
<div class="hr">
<input type="button" id="hr" class="hrButton" value="HR" onclick="funchr();" />
<table id="hrtable"> </table>
```

Comment: what are you using? pure JS or jQuery?

Comment: @TreeNguyen Isn't it obvious from the code?

Comment: @TomášZato I thought only jQuery has the $(...)

Comment: need in js . i have used jquery for some parts actually its a large program and i have posted here a single module

Comment: @VikramSrinivasan how many lines would it have in your table? Or just 3 simple buttons?

Comment: i have around 9 buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can really save yourself a variable assignment here:

```
button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("blah blah"));
```

Regarding the table, I advise to make a helper function. I will assume you want one button per table cell, though you didn't really bother explaining how you want the table to look:

```js
function addButtonToTable(button, table) {
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  // Get first row of table
  var row = table.rows[0];
  // Create new row if row doesn't exist
  if(!row) {
    row = document.createElement("row");
    table.appendChild(row);
  }
  // Add button to table cell
  cell.appendChild(button);
  row.appendChild(cell);
}
// Your old function
function funchr()
{   
    // Remove hrdiv
    var div = document.getElementById("hr");
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    // Get table
 var table = document.getElementById("hrtable");
 
 var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");       
    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("VIEW PROFILE"));                                
    btn.setAttribute("id","viewid");
    btn.setAttribute("class","vp");
    addButtonToTable(btn, table);
    
    btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        
    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("EMPLOYEE DIRECTORY"));                               
    btn.setAttribute("id","empdir");
    btn.setAttribute("class","ed");
    addButtonToTable(btn, table);
    
    btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        
    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("CREATE ABSENCE"));                                     
    btn.setAttribute("id","crabs");
    btn.setAttribute("class","ca");
    addButtonToTable(btn, table);
}
// This is just JSFiddle thing, remove it in your page
window.funchr = funchr;
```

```html
<input type="button" id="hr" class="hrButton" value="HR" onclick="funchr();" />
<table id="hrtable"> </table>
```

Comment: thank you @Tomas and what changes to do for 3 rows and 3 columns as i have 9 buttons

Comment: @VikramSrinivasan Why didn't you post that in your question? Why are you intentionally making it harder for others to help you? If there's multiple rows you will have to reference each row by `id`. I am not editing this answer, it's correct answer to your question, next time ask question correctly.

Comment: sorry man i was creating for a large complex project and have forgot it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are deleting the whole element `<div class="hr">`
so we are removing the table inside it too,
instead we have to remove the button which can be identified by `#hr`

```js
function funchr()
{   
 $( "#hr" ).remove();
 var table = document.getElementById("hrtable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    
  
 var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");      
    var t = document.createTextNode("VIEW PROFILE");      
    btn.appendChild(t);                                
    btn.setAttribute("id","viewid");
    btn.setAttribute("class","vp");
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.appendChild(btn);
    
    td = document.createElement("td")
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        
    var t = document.createTextNode("EMPLOYEE DIRECTORY");       
    btn.appendChild(t);                               
    btn.setAttribute("id","empdir");
    btn.setAttribute("class","ed");
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.appendChild(btn);
  
    td = document.createElement("td")
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        
    var t = document.createTextNode("CREATE ABSENCE");       
    btn.appendChild(t);                                
    btn.setAttribute("id","crabs");
    btn.setAttribute("class","ca");
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell3.appendChild(btn);
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hr">
<input type="button" id="hr" class="hrButton" value="HR" onclick="funchr();" />
<table id="hrtable"> </table>
```

Comment: How does this add buttons to the table as OP requested?

Comment: where is adding these buttons to the table

Comment: @VikramSrinivasan I understood your question. It's pretty clear actually.

Comment: sorry @VikramSrinivasan
you were clear 
will edit the answer now